# Can you connect two keyboard ribbon cords together?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Hi I was wondering how can I connect two keyboard ribbon cords together by melting them together or do I need to do something else to connect them if it is possible... Sorry if that is not enough information that is all that I can think of adding...

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well my laptop was not working (it was refurbished so I thought it was just the end for it) so I was curious on what the inside of the ribbon looked like so I cut it with scissors (stupidest idea ever now) and found out a wire for the screen was disconnected and now the keyboard is broken... I hope that said what I want to accomplish in more detail

Comment: No, those cables can't be mended. You'll have to find a new cable and replace it if you have the chops for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing will be to replace the keyboard from the laptop manufacturer.  The replacement will come with a new ribbon cable attached.

Technically speaking, all cables can be repaired.  However, based on your actions, the repair is most definitely out of your skill level.  You could pay someone to repair it, but that would most likely be more expensive than replacing the entire keyboard.

Comment: Wait so there is a way to fix it? How can it be fixed (i know it is out of my skill level im just curious but I wont cut it)

Comment: You would need to create a bridge for each wire using extra wire and solder, and you would need to ensure that the cable can't touch any other part, so you would need to add protection. It needs to be done tight or you risk that it won't fit in your laptop. I would still just replace the keyboard. Far better option than to repair it.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like hell... It must take a very long time for anyone to do that